# HAL_UART_Transmit sends wrong data

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, uart

When ch = 0x80, on PC I receive 0x00,
When ch = 0x40, on PC I receive 0x80,
When ch = 0x20, on PC I receive 0x60,
When ch = 0x10, on PC I receive 0x10,
When ch = 0x08, on PC I receive 0x08,
When ch = 0x04, on PC I receive 0x04,
When ch = 0x02, on PC I receive 0x02,
When ch = 0x01, on PC I receive 0x01,

Can't figure what is going on here... I am attaching USART Initialization, Transmit Function and Main. I should be software issue, already tested the hardware and it's ok. MCU = STM32L011

```
void InitUSART(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    USARTx_CLK_ENABLE();

    UartHandle.Instance = USARTx;
    UartHandle.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    UartHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    UartHandle.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    UartHandle.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    UartHandle.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    UartHandle.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    //UartHandle.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_ENABLE;
    HAL_UART_Init(&UartHandle);

    /* Transmit Configuration */
    USARTx_TX_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USARTx_TX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = USARTx_TX_AF;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(USARTx_TX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Receive Configuration */
    USARTx_RX_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USARTx_RX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = USARTx_TX_AF;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(USARTx_RX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USARTx_IRQn, 0, 1);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USARTx_IRQn);
}

HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
{
  uint16_t* tmp;
  uint32_t tickstart = 0;

  /* Check that a Tx process is not already ongoing */
  if(huart->gState == HAL_UART_STATE_READY)
  {
    if((pData == NULL ) || (Size == 0U))
    {
      return  HAL_ERROR;
    }

    /* In case of 9bits/No Parity transfer, pData buffer provided as input paramter 
       should be aligned on a u16 frontier, as data to be filled into TDR will be 
       handled through a u16 cast. */
    if ((huart->Init.WordLength == UART_WORDLENGTH_9B) && (huart->Init.Parity == UART_PARITY_NONE))
    {
      if((((uint32_t)pData)&1) != 0)
      {
        return  HAL_ERROR;
      }
    }

    /* Process Locked */
    __HAL_LOCK(huart);

    huart->ErrorCode = HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE;
    huart->gState = HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_TX;

    /* Init tickstart for timeout managment*/
    tickstart = HAL_GetTick();

    huart->TxXferSize = Size;
    huart->TxXferCount = Size;
    while(huart->TxXferCount > 0U)
    {
      huart->TxXferCount--;
      if(UART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(huart, UART_FLAG_TXE, RESET, tickstart, Timeout) != HAL_OK)
      {
        return HAL_TIMEOUT;
      }
      if ((huart->Init.WordLength == UART_WORDLENGTH_9B) && (huart->Init.Parity == UART_PARITY_NONE))
      {
        tmp = (uint16_t*) pData;
        huart->Instance->TDR = (*tmp & (uint16_t)0x01FFU);
        pData += 2U;
      }
      else
      {
        huart->Instance->TDR = (*pData++ & (uint8_t)0xFFU);
      }
    }
    if(UART_WaitOnFlagUntilTimeout(huart, UART_FLAG_TC, RESET, tickstart, Timeout) != HAL_OK)
    {
      return HAL_TIMEOUT;
    }

    /* At end of Tx process, restore huart->gState to Ready */
    huart->gState = HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(huart);

    return HAL_OK;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  /* STM32L0xx HAL library initialization:
       - Configure the Flash prefetch, Flash preread and Buffer caches
       - Systick timer is configured by default as source of time base, but user
             can eventually implement his proper time base source (a general purpose
             timer for example or other time source), keeping in mind that Time base
             duration should be kept 1ms since PPP_TIMEOUT_VALUEs are defined and
             handled in milliseconds basis.
       - Low Level Initialization
     */
    HAL_Init();

    /* Configure the system clock to 32 MHz */
    SystemClock_Config();

    InitUSART();
    //Transmit(txBuffer, 2);

    extern UART_HandleTypeDef UartHandle;
    uint16_t ch = 0x80;
    TransmitEnable();
    while(1){
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, &ch, 1, 0xFF);
        HAL_Delay(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly baudrate inaccuracy. If you are deriving your system clock from a built-in RC oscillator, it might not be accurate enough for RS-232. Also, perhaps needless to say, ensure there is a signal ground.

Comment: @Lundin STM ones are accurate enough. It is known problem with the AVR uCs. I would suspect wrong clock initialization.

Comment: Signal ground is ok. Oscilloscope shows 110us per bit which is ok imo.

Comment: @velizarw 110us means baudrate 9090 bps. That is not ok at all and will not work. You need 104us for baudrate 9600.

Comment: @P__J__ Still it is good design practice to always use external crystal/resonator whenever the application contains a serial bus.

Comment: To ma it sounds like baudrate mismatch due to clock problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a clock issue after all. I was using internal 16 MHz oscillator (HSI) multiplied up to 32 MHz with PLL. Single baud width on 9600 baudrate was 110us. Now I switched to 4 MHz (internal MSI) and I am getting 104us per baud. Communication is flawless now.

```
RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct ={0};
RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0)!= HAL_OK)
{
  while(1);
}

__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);
__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_DISABLE();
```

Answer (score -1):

Acording your sent source file, you programmed the usart as "8 bits", but this STM HAL routine compute data_bits+parity_bit=8bits(your selection). For standard text transmission, for this STM HAL should be: 9 bits (8_data_bits+one_parity_bit).

Comment: No, `UartHandle.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;` it means - no parity Even if he set the parity bit the HAL recalculates the "register level" word length accordingly.  Answer is wrong